# Best way to check for specific types

Tags: c#

Normally I do this:

```
if (Animal is Dog)
{
    Doc d = (Dog)Animal;
    // d. etc..
} 
else if (Animal is Cat) 
{
    Cat c = (Cat)Animal;
    // c. ....
}
```

Is this a good way or are there better ways to implement this code above (performance, ...) ?

Should it be like this?:

```
Dog d = Animal as Dog;

if (d != null;)
{
    // d. etc..
} 
else if (Animal is Cat) 
{
    Cat c = (Cat)Animal;
    // c. ....
}
```

Or maybe like this?:

```
Dog d = Animal as Dog;
Cat c;

if (d != null;)
{
    // d. etc..
} 
else if ((c = Animal as Cat) != null) 
{
    // c. ....
}
```

Or maybe something else?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ideally, you should aim for just:

```
Animal.DoWhateverYouNeedDone();
```

That is, implement the polymorphic behavior (if it's a dog, do a dog thing, if it's a cat, do a cat thing, etc.) in the classes themselves. So instead of this:

```
if (Animal is Dog) {
    var d = Animal as Dog;
    d.Bark();
}
if (Animal is Cat) {
    var c = Animal as Cat;
    c.Meow();
}
```

Do this:

```
Animal.Speak();

// where:

public class Dog: Animal {
    public void Speak() {
        this.Bark();
    }
    // ---- snip -----
}
public class Cat: Animal {
    public void Speak() {
        this.Meow();
    }
    // ---- snip -----
}
```

Comment: Exactly! This is the definition itself of polymorphism.

Comment: +1 Specifically for the first thing you said. If you care what type you should only accept that specific type or its subtypes in the majority of circumstances.

Comment: This is true, but sometimes you can't (I have one example where the classes exist in a library, which doesn't have access to other classes that would be needed by the method), and you haven't answered the question for those cases.

Comment: @pdr: Of course there are cases where this doesn't work, and the cause is usually bad design - either on your own part, or in a library you're using. When that happens, and you can't change the design, use whatever works, but by all means, wrap the ugliness in a sane wrapper and expose only that to other code.

Comment: It's not even always bad design. These classes are messages, sent from one app to another, which acts on them. The same message objects need to be exposed to both apps, but the action classes that are generated should never be exposed to the sender. So it makes sense to have a factory on the receiver, which generates an action based on message type.

Comment: @pdr: wouldn't you then be serializing your messages anyway, and parse them back out on the other end? You can easily reintroduce the polymorphism while parsing, and you'll still have what boils down to a switch statement in a factory method, but at least you're not dispatching on an object's run-time type. I'd even argue that if you are passing objects around directly (e.g. using shared memory), it would still be more elegant to give them a property to report what kind of message they are and dispatch based on that.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean by "You can easily reintroduce the polymorphism while parsing" but it seems overkill to avoid casting at ALL costs. My real point is that the question is "which is the best way to do this?" and you've (rightly) suggested avoiding it, without answering the question for cases where the design forces or encourages you to do it anyway.

Answer (score 8):

tdammers answer is the correct way to do it, and 99% of the time you should do it that way.

very occasionally there maybe situations when you don't want to do it that way. In these circumstances I'd use the 'as and check for null' approach. Indeed [FxCop will actually warn you that you are casting twice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx) (once with is and once with an actual cast) in your first approach

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on what behaviour you're trying to access. Expounding on your previous example:

```
        if (Animal is Dog)
        {
            Dog d = (Dog)Animal;
            d.BuryBone();
        }
        else if (Animal is Cat)
        {
            Cat c = (Cat)Animal;
            c.DrinkSaucerOfMilk();
        }
```

This is perfect if you're after dog or cat *specific* behaviour. Otherwise if you want to use the more general methods of the base class:

```
Animal.EatFood();
```

Or if you've defined an interface:

```
IAnimal tiddles = new Cat();           
IAnimal rex = new Dog();

tiddles.EatFood();
rex.EatFood();
```